# Python Class, how to skip a wrong entry and proceed to next entry

Tags: python, exception

I have created this Python Class for entry of some products that can either be new, or used, or refurbished (case insensitivity achieved by the `.lower()` function). Any other entry of condition parameter should give an error (ValueError) and I want the code to proceed to the next line.

`Random_Product_1` is first and perfect new object. No problems with this. I have made an intentional error with the condition of the next object `Random_Product_2`. This should print the `ValueError`. It does but also additional error stuff. This has cause the code to stop on its track. The next line of code making the object (correct condition values entered) is simply not run.

I am basically trying to make the code skip of erroneous entries like `Random_Product_2` to the the next line of code. Here is my basic code so far upon which I plan to build other stuff once I solve this issue.

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, Id, price, inventory, condition):
        self.condition = condition.lower()
        if self.condition != "new" and self.condition != "used" and self.condition != "refurbished":
            raise ValueError('condition can only be new or used or refurbished')
        self.Id = Id
        self.price = price
        self.inventory = inventory

Random_Product_1 = Product('What_is_this', 50, 81, "Used") # defined perfectly
Random_Product_2 = Product('What_is_this', 50, 85, "Useed") # not defined at all, code doesn't go to next line
Random_Product_3 = Product('What_is_this', 500, 805, "Used") # This is not run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem description isn't precise: the `if` statement has no way to "skip to the next entry", because that next entry is controlled by the calling program, not `__init__`.  All you can do in the initializer is to control the set-up of this *one* object.

The root problem is that you *say* you want the program to continue, but you've used a language facility that *specifically* aborts the program.  Very simply, you need to decide which of these you want.  Assuming that you want to complete the current initialization as smoothly as possible, try this: check the given choice against a list of valid choices.  If it's not in that list, issue a simple message and complete the initialization as best you can.

```
def __init__(self, Id, price, inventory, condition):
    valid_condition = ("new", "used", "refurbished")
    self.condition = condition.lower()
    if self.condition not in valid_condition:
        print('condition can only be new or used or refurbished. ',
              'Setting to "unknown"')
        self.condition = "unknown"

    self.Id = Id
    self.price = price
    self.inventory = inventory
```

Is that the effect you want?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you chose to raise an exception so that an instance with an illegal value is not created at all, so you don't have to deal with it afterwards. Why not. However, for a program to continue after an exception is raised, you need to use a `try` statement. Let's create the products in a loop and use just one `try` statement inside this loop:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, Id, price, inventory, condition):
        self.condition = condition.lower()
        if self.condition not in ("new", "used", "refurbished"):
            raise ValueError('condition can only be new or used or refurbished')
        self.Id = Id
        self.price = price
        self.inventory = inventory

    # special method for a more readable print()
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(self.Id, self.price, self.inventory, self.condition)

data = (('A', 50, 81, "Used"),
        ('B', 50, 85, "Useed"), 
        ('C', 500, 805, "Used"))

product_list = []

for item in data:
    try:
        new_product = Product(*item)
    except:
        # do nothing with the exception
        pass
    else:
        product_list.append(new_product)

# check if product 'B' exists
for item in product_list:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
A   50  81  used
C   500 805 used
```